# NLTK Stopwords Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, nltk

I'm trying to use NLTK stop words while performing sentimental analysis using flask.

I've tried downloading the stop words "English" and have pointed it in app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F4_HIGHMEM
env_variables: 
    NLTK_DATA: 'nltk_data'
```

Please find error below:

```
*********************************************************************
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    Resource [93mstopwords[0m not found.
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    [31m>>> import nltk
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    >>> nltk.download('stopwords')
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    [0m
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    Attempted to load [93mcorpora/stopwords[0m
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]    Searched in:
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - 'nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/root/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/env/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/env/share/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/env/lib/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]      - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
2020-06-08 10:38:55 default[20200608t160417]  **************************************************
```

Please suggest!!!

Comment: Have you used the NLTK Downloader to obtain the 'stopwords' data, as the error is suggesting?

Comment: I've resolved this issue by just adding corpora/stopwords inside nltk_data and placing the file inside it